# unable to run curl in gitbash

Tags: windows, curl, git-bash

Hi I am using gitbash in windows.

```
curl -X GET  "https://emp-pp-sr.retina.myorg.net/subjects/topic.internal.any.v1-value/versions/latest"
--cert C:/Users/NGO109/Documents/decodedca.pem 
--key C:/Users/NGO109/Documents/decodedkey.pem  | jq
```

When I try to execute I am getting below error

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
> certificate More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
> not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
> situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above

Can someone pls help me here? Thanks in advance